# how can I refer to a component created via DynamicComponent in Blazor?

Tags: dynamic, components, blazor, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm rendering components using DinamicComponent and I need to call a function found in the child component.
I can't find the equivalent of using @ref for the DinamicComponents so that I can reference to call the function.

This is the parent component

```
 <div class="tab-content">
            @foreach (VerticalTabComponent.TabModel oneTabItem in VerticalTabsList)
            {
                <div class="tab-pane fade show @(oneTabItem.TabIndex == SelectedTabIndex ? "active" : "")" @key=@($"VTabDivDynamic_{TabPrefix}_{oneTabItem.TabIndex.ToString()}")>
                    <DynamicComponent
                              Type=@System.Type.GetType(oneTabItem.TabComponent)
                              Parameters=@oneTabItem.TabParameters>
                    </DynamicComponent>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
```

This is the code in Blazor Component Tab

```
 public partial class TabComponent
{
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> InsertUpdateCallback { get; set; }

    
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
       await CallAnyfunctionAsync();
    }
    private async Task<bool> LoadDataGrid()
    {
       //this is the function I need to call from parent
    }
}
```

How can I call the Load Grid function from the parent component?

Answer (score 4):

There is an easy solution. Not sure if that is new but the ref-attribut does exist for the DynamicComponent! You can use it like this:

```
<DynamicComponent Type="typeof(MyComponent)" Parameters="@MyParameters" @ref="dc" />
```

and in Code-Behind:

```
private DynamicComponent? dc;

private MyComponent? MyComponentRef
{
    get
    {
        return (MyComponent?)dc?.Instance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally in Blazor we use `@Ref` to get a reference to a component, but as you've seen this won't work with a `DynamicComponent`.

A workaround for this would be to add a `[Parameter]` to the component called something like `Register` which is an action with the generic type set as the component type. You can then add code to handle `OnParametersSet` to call this method in the component.

You can then add a `Register` parameter in your `TabParameters` which gets updated with a reference.

Example code below would be added to the `SurveyPrompt` component:

```cs
    /// <summary>
    ///  will be called when params set
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter] public  Action<SurveyPrompt> Register { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        if (Register != null)
        {
            // register this component
                Register(this);
        }
    }
```

You add a `Register` parameter with an `Action<type>` value. Here's an example:

```cs
    SurveyPrompt sp1 = null;


    void Register1(SurveyPrompt survey)
    {
        sp1 = survey;
        Console.WriteLine("SP1 has title " + sp1.Title);
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Action<SurveyPrompt> p1 = Register1;

        params1 = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "Title", "Survey Title Here" },
            { "Register", p1 }
        };
    }

    IDictionary<string, object> params1;
```

Comment: This is great, but it's quite confusing what SurveyPrompt is meant to be in your example code? Does it represent the parent component? Or a separate class?